# How to use KeyListener with audio?

Tags: java

Well, I'm trying to make a program simulating a launchpad. But for that, I need to open the program and press, for example, the "Q" key, it play a sound. How could I do this? In short: "Handshake specifies a key, and while it is being pressed, tap a sound" If you can answer, even grateful! xD
I click a button on my keyboard, and an error, the following code appears music:

```
try {
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream (getClass () getResource       ("1.wav").); 
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info (Clip.class, sound.getFormat ()); 
Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine (info); 
clip.open (sound); 
clip.start (); 
if (playing == false) {
clip.stop (); 
Else {} 
clip.start (); 
} 
} Catch (Exception e) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Fatal err"); 
}
```

I created a KeyListener so that when I click, the sound plays, but the following error appears:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence at (Unknown Source) 
javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence at (Unknown Source) 
com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream at (Unknown Source) 
javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream at (Unknown Source) 
at Programa.LaunchPad.som1 (LaunchPad.java: 41) 
Programa.LaunchPad at $ BotãoAção.keyReleased (LaunchPad.java: 201) 
java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent at (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.processEvent (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Container.processEvent (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.Window.processEvent at (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent at (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent at (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent at (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions at (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent at (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl at (Unknown Source) 
java.awt.EventQueue.access at $ 200 (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventQueue $ 3.run (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventQueue $ 3.run (Unknown Source) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method) 
java.security.ProtectionDomain at $ 1.doIntersectionPrivilege (Unknown Source) 
java.security.ProtectionDomain at $ 1.doIntersectionPrivilege (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventQueue $ 4.run (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventQueue $ 4.run (Unknown Source) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method) 
java.security.ProtectionDomain at $ 1.doIntersectionPrivilege (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents (Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run (Unknown Source)
```

Im using the library AWT, and Swing. (With JPanel, ImageIcon, sound)

Comment: Please try to flesh out your question. What GUI library? Android? Swing? SWT? AWT? Other? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Google: java keylistener, and then google: java sound.

Comment: It's an NPE. What don't you know about Null Pointer Exceptions?

Comment: I want to click in one button, and play one sound, but this error appears. What i have to do? Where is the error?

Comment: its telling you *exactly* where the error is:  Programa.LaunchPad.som1 (LaunchPad.java: 41)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated problem looks to be this part:

```
getClass().getResource("1.wav")
```

i'm betting that doesn't do what you think it does, and returns null.

step through your code in the debugger to see what is going on there, and see if/why it can't find your wav.